# YouTube comment search

Tags: youtube, search, comments

Everybody says that there is a comment search on YouTube, but I do not see any. I mean that I get this

[image]

when go to the  http://www.youtube.com/comment_search. Do proponents of this URL check it before recommending to others?

I would be especially happy with something http://data.stackexchange.com - like, where you can query in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube has retired their comment search feature (used to be accessible at http://www.youtube.com/comment_search).

Comment: See my updated question. It says why I ask it.

Comment: I fear the answer is "in your dreams" (and mine) then.