# Is there a clever way to search YouTube comments of a specific video?

Tags: youtube, search

I found a service called **Juphy** which unfortunately did not work even though it said they offer searching through YouTube comments.

I thought of scrolling down until all comments are shown and then just searching in the page but the browser gets a bit unstable after a while of scrolling and it isn't the best solution anyway.

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50140/youtube-comment-search) is 6 years old and not quite the same so I think it is Ok to post a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to search for a keyword in Youtube comments of a specific video, not using stuff like RegExp.

https://ytcomment.kmcat.uk/

Does exactly this. Tried and worked.

Comment: This is amazing thanks so much.

Comment: This website stopped working for me, does it still work for you?